# USB Port slowing down to zero speed when copying files

Tags: 20.04, usb

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop edition. My seagate drive is connected to the Ubuntu machine via the USB 3 port. I have total 3 traditional USB ports on my laptop. On all three ports I have the same issue - when copying files from Home folder to Seagate, the speed begins at 145 MB/s and then quickly drops to 0 MB/s within just few seconds. It begins copyin files at high speeds then quickly stops copying as the speed closes to zero transfer speed.

So alternatively I installed samba share on this Ubuntu machine and shared my Home folder to my local network.I am able to access Ubuntu Home folder from my windows laptop within the same local network, but when I try to transfer or copy over the files from ubuntu to windows the speed is super slow something like 50 kb/s. It would take forever to copy over large data.

I also tried borrowing a docking station that has the USB C port option to connect to my ubuntu machine. This idea also failed because the speed started high and then quickly dropped to zero speed file transfer.

I also tried installing vmware windows in the ubntu host. I tried accessing the seagate from inside the vm but issue remains the same. the file transfer hangs up and says that large hard disk needed which is something to do with how the vm is ssetup i guess.

Anyways I have run out of ideas on how to backup data from this ubntu machine to external hardd rive. Please advise any ideas

Thanks

```
z@zbook-lp:~$ free -h

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       1.6Gi        27Gi        28Mi       2.0Gi        29Gi
Swap:          31Gi          0B        31Gi

z@zbook-lp:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness

vm.swappiness = 60


z@zbook-lp:~$ swapon -s

Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/nvme0n1p5                          partition   33430524    0   -2

z@zbook-lp:~$ top

Tasks: 347 total,   1 running, 346 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.1 us,  0.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  32037.9 total,  28288.8 free,   1705.4 used,   2043.7 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  32647.0 total,  32647.0 free,      0.0 used.  29840.9 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                     
   1103 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.7   0.0   0:26.56 irq/141-nvidia                                                                                                                              
   4571 z         20   0   12340   4312   3452 R   0.7   0.0   0:01.07 top                                                                                                                                         
   1105 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:09.34 nv_queue                                                                                                                                    
   1626 root      20   0  186252  59836  36156 S   0.3   0.2   0:47.54 Xorg                                                                                                                                        
   1795 z         20   0 4468244 340796 120884 S   0.3   1.0   1:25.47 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                 
   2884 z         20   0   16.3g 101984  82416 S   0.3   0.3   0:04.63 chrome                                                                                                                                      
   3452 z         20   0   20.4g 158084  98240 S   0.3   0.5   3:27.71 chrome                                                                                                                                      
   4532 z         20   0  817880  54404  39056 S   0.3   0.2   0:05.38 gnome-terminal-                                                                                                                             
      1 root      20   0  169928  11688   8196 S   0.0   0.0   0:03.22 systemd                                                                                                                                     
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd                                                                                                                                    
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                                                                                      
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                                                                                                  
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                        
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                                                                                                
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                                 
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:01.76 rcu_sched                                                                                                                                   
     12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 migration/0                                                                                                                                 
     13 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                                                                                               
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                                                                                     
     15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                                                                                     
     16 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/1                                                                                                                               
     17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.22 migration/1                                                                                                                                 
     18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                                                 
     20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                        
     21 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2                                                                                                                                     
     22 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/2                                                                                                                               
     23 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.22 migration/2                                                                                                                                 
     24 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/2                                                                                                                                 
     26 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                        
     27 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/3                                                                                                                                     
     28 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/3                                                                                                                               
     29 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.23 migration/3                                                                                                                                 
     30 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/3                                                                                                                                 
     32 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                        
     33 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/4                                                                                                                                     
     34 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/4                                                                                                                               
     35 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.22 migration/4                                                                                                                                 
     36 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/4                                                                                                                                 
     38 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/4:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                        
     39 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/5                                                                                                                                     
     40 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/5                                                                                                                               
     41 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.22 migration/5                                                                                                                                 
     42 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/5                                                                                                                                 
     44 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/5:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                        
     45 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/6 
     
     
     
z@zbook-lp:~$ grep -i Seagate Portable Drive /var/log/syslog*

/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 13:17:55 zbook-lp kernel: [25225.613528] usb 4-2.3.1: Manufacturer: Seagate
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 13:17:56 zbook-lp kernel: [25225.671427] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Portable         0712 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 13:18:08 zbook-lp ntfs-3g[33774]: Mounted /dev/sda1 (Read-Write, label "Seagate Portable Drive", NTFS 3.1)
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 13:18:08 zbook-lp systemd[1]: Finished Clean the /media/z/Seagate Portable Drive mount point.
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 13:18:08 zbook-lp udisksd[770]: Mounted /dev/sda1 at /media/z/Seagate Portable Drive on behalf of uid 1000
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 13:26:58 zbook-lp udisksd[770]: Cleaning up mount point /media/z/Seagate Portable Drive (device 8:1 is not mounted)
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 13:26:58 zbook-lp ntfs-3g[33774]: Unmounting /dev/sda1 (Seagate Portable Drive)
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 13:26:58 zbook-lp systemd[1]: media-z-Seagate\x20Portable\x20Drive.mount: Succeeded.
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 13:26:58 zbook-lp systemd[965]: media-z-Seagate\x20Portable\x20Drive.mount: Succeeded.
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 13:26:58 zbook-lp systemd[1545]: media-z-Seagate\x20Portable\x20Drive.mount: Succeeded.
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 13:26:58 zbook-lp systemd[1]: Stopping Clean the /media/z/Seagate Portable Drive mount point...
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 13:26:58 zbook-lp systemd[1]: clean-mount-point@media-z-Seagate\x20Portable\x20Drive.service: Succeeded.
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 13:26:58 zbook-lp systemd[1]: Stopped Clean the /media/z/Seagate Portable Drive mount point.
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 16:56:27 zbook-lp kernel: [12062.853501] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: Seagate
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 16:56:27 zbook-lp kernel: [12062.881178] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Portable         0712 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 16:56:40 zbook-lp ntfs-3g[5209]: Mounted /dev/sda1 (Read-Write, label "Seagate Portable Drive", NTFS 3.1)
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 16:56:40 zbook-lp systemd[1]: Finished Clean the /media/z/Seagate Portable Drive mount point.
/var/log/syslog:Sep  2 16:56:40 zbook-lp udisksd[793]: Mounted /dev/sda1 at /media/z/Seagate Portable Drive on behalf of uid 1000
```

Comment: Hello @oumuamua. Sounds like the disk could have some issues.

Comment: My experience is that the speed to hard disk drives and SSDs can be quite good via USB3. The speed is better with the file system ext4 than with NTFS. Most USB pendrives are slow (much slower than hard disk drives and SSDs) particularly when they have been written to several times. The reason why the speed is fast in the beginning and then slower, if often that at first it is writing to a buffer in RAM which is very fast, and when the buffer is full, it must write to the drive's memory cells, and it can be quite slow. - But if it is zero speed (for a minute or so), something is *wrong*.

Comment: @guiverc yes this Ubuntu Desktop 20.04
I want to upgrade to 21 but want to backup all files before i initiate upgrade

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s` and `top` and `grep -i sdX /var/log/syslog*` (changing sdX to the device name of your external HDD).

Comment: @heynnema
I have edited the question with your commands.

Comment: @guiverc I have edited question mentioning that Ubuntu Desktop edition 20.04. Thanks.

Comment: Have you found Gnome Disks utility on your machine and performed a disk benchmark?

Comment: You might want to use some other device that utilizes any of the USB ports and perform backups.  I am thinking a flash drive, but if you have an SD / microSD slot on your laptop, that could be an option.

Comment: I noticed that the Seagate is using NTFS3.1  ... You might want to see if this format is well-supported in Linux.

Comment: @oumuamua Other than the swap partition being ridiculously large, I don't see the problem yet. Edit your question and show me `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` (upload it to https://paste.ubuntu.com if it's a lot of data), and open the `Disks` app, go to the 3-dot icon, and choose SMART Data & Tests. Get to the data window, resize the window to show all data, take a screenshot, and edit it into your question. Thanks.

Comment: @oumuamua How large is the external drive? Does it have its own AC power brick? Is it plugged directly into a USB3 port on the computer, or does it go through a POWERED USB hub?

Comment: What Seagate model drive?  Some use Shingled Magnetic Recording (SMR) which can be very slow. google seagate disks smr to see.

Comment: @mondotofu suggestion helped. I used a WD 4 TB drive to copy 32 GB data at 120 MB/Sec. 
The seagate model is SRD0NF1 2TB.
Looks like the issue may not be the USB port. The issue might be with the seagate drive itself.
WD speed started at 150 and then slowly came down to 110 after two minutes of file transfer. 

The SMART Data & Tests is greyed out for some reason, unable to run that option in the Disks app

Also I was able to copy 100 GB worth data into the WD drive - speed started at 180 and ended up around 90 after about 12 minutes of transfer time.

Comment: Next I will try using the seagate on the windows machine to check if the issue exists.